# Разница слэша и обратного слэша для include (PHP)

Tags: php, классы, автозагрузка

Автозагрузка классов в PHP:

```
 function autoloadMainClasses($class_name){
       $class_name = str_replace('\\','/',$class_name);
       include_once $class_name . '.php';
    }
 spl_autoload_register('autoloadMainClasses');
```

Вопрос, а собственно надо ли менять обратный слэш на обычный, если и без этого **include** работает?

Comment: Лучше используйте composer autoload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменять не обязательно, так как Windows понимает оба разделителя, достаточно использовать в коде разделитель Linux.

Однако важно учитывать тип разделителя, так как все функции, отдающие путь (вроде `realpath`), отдают его с специфичными для операционной системы разделителями.

Также при обработке путей удобно использовать константу **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR**. Она содержит разделитель пути для текущей операционной системы.

Например, в вашем случае код может быть таким, но только если не использовали обратные слэши:

```
function autoloadMainClasses($class_name){
       $class_name = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name);
       include_once $class_name . '.php';
    }
 spl_autoload_register('autoloadMainClasses');
```